# HTTP_REFERER redirect php code not working?

Tags: php, http, redirect, referer

The following script is in the header of my website.  I want to use google analytics to monitor the amount of traffic that a specified website is sending to the website I am driving to.  The script will redirect users from my website to the website I am driving traffic to.  I tested the script out and it's not redirecting.  I put a link to my website on another website I have to test the script out but I was not redirected to the website I am trying to drive traffic to.  Any ideas?

```
 <?php
 $ref = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
 if ( $ref != 'http://www.websitetrafficiscomingfrom.com' )
exit;
 ?>

 <?php if ( $ref == 'http://www.websitetrafficiscomingfrom.com' ) { ?>

 <script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-32605120-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

</script>

 <!-- <?php } else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != "") { ?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-32554427-2']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
 })();

 </script> -->

 <meta http-equiv='REFRESH" content='0;url=websitetrafficissupposedtogoto.com'>

 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: "Any ideas" --- hire a developer. SO is not a free debug-my-scripts-because-I'm-too-lazy tool

Comment: What are you doing here? This looks kinda shady

Comment: $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], is very unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, a referrer will always be either blank, or a full URL (including the trailing `/`, if needed). Therefore it will NEVER be the value you ask for. Consequently, you will ALWAYS die and result in a blank page that doesn't do anything.

Aside from that, I really have to wonder what you're doing. Your question doesn't seem to make any sense when compared to the code that accompanies it, and what code there is seems redundant. I mean, you check if `a != b`, exiting if so. Otherwise, check if `a == b`, as if there's some chance it might suddenly not be true anymore. To make matters worse, you have a commented-out `else` block, showing that at some point you clearly intended to yet again check if `a != b`, even though your code has already died if that's the case...

I would suggest dropping this code entirely. It's not useful or reliable to use `HTTP_REFERER`, the only thing I would use it for is as a feeble barrier to block most hotlinking attempts. Even then, only with caution.

Comment: So what's the best way to do it? I want to run a script that will monitor traffic coming from a specific website going to a website I am trying to drive traffic to.  I'm trying to drive traffic to an iTunes product page but iTunes doesn't give you the option to have google analytics on to your app page.  So I need a script that does 2 things:

1. Monitors and filters out the traffic coming from the specified website that is linking to the site I am driving traffic to.

2. Uses google analytics to track the traffic once its filtered.